# Como redirecionar o usuário para outra página com o CodeiIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou iniciando com o CodeIgniter e estou com uma pequena dificuldade em linkar as páginas.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('nomeApp/login');?>">Login</a>
</li>
```

Meu controller está assim

```
class Homepage extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('veloxmob/index');
}

public function login()
{
    $this->load->view('login/login');
}}
```

Comment: Precisa ter um controlador nomeApp, com a função login. Nessa função login, você retorna a sua view

Comment: Agora só basta pegar o resultado de $this->load->view e imprimir na tela com o echo

Comment: Pode me mostrar um exemplo ? Pois está sendo um pouco confuso já que estou começando agora no code, esse echo eu insiro dentro do meu controller ou no link ?

Comment: echo $this->load->view('veloxmob/index');
 vai imprimir o index.php da pasta veloxmob (dentro da pasta de views)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nessa sua tag está sendo redirecionado para o controller nomeApp, porém o seu controller é Homepage

tente substituir o nomeApp para Homepage na tag

```
<li class="nav-item mr-3">
    <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="<?php echo base_url('Homepage/login');?>">Login</a>
</li>
```